# Возможно ли обработать ошибку в конструкторе класса, проброшенную из конструктора другого класса?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имею служебный класс по работе с text-to-speech, в его конструкторе идет выбор необходимого языка синтезатора, но проблема в том, что этот язык может быть не установлен у пользователя и тогда, в случае возникновения ошибки, выбирается первый по списку язык

```
//это конструктор
public SpeechSynth()
{
    //выбираем голос по-умолчанию
    try
    {
        SelectedVoice = _Synthesizer
                            .GetInstalledVoices()
                            .First(v => v.VoiceInfo.Description.Contains("France"));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //тогда выбираем первый доступный
        SelectedVoice = _Synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices().First();
        Debug.WriteLine("Ошибка выбора голоса при инициализации.");
        //throw;
    }
}
```

Вот начало ViewModel

```
private SpeechSynth _Speech;

//ctor
public MainViewModel()
{
    try
    {
        _Speech = new SpeechSynth();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //здесь хотелось бы сообщить пользователю, что целевой язык не доступен
        //требуется его установить.                
    }

}
```

Так вот, в конструкторе VM в блоке `catch` я еще ничего не могу сообщить пользователю (вызвать `MessageBox` к примеру). Как такую проблему можно решить? Может какая-нибудь ленивая загрузка или еще чего-нибудь?

P.S. Пояснение, в принципе конечно, если зафигачить MessageBox в VM, то его можно показать, но это не то. Для вызова MessageBox используется служебный класс сообщений, который, к слову, тоже из конструктора инициализацию проходит, кроме того с синтезатором еще кое-чего делается из констурктора (я это все убрал, чтоб не мешать главное со второстепенным). В случае ошибки `_Speech` получется == null, и с ним все равно не получиться работать.

Comment: Так а в чём проблема то? Если раскомментировать `thow` в `SpeechSynth` то вы при вызове `new SpeechSynth();` попадете в `catch` в `MainViewModel`.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan Попаду и тут же упаду, и вызвать `MessageBox` тоже не смогу.

Comment: [этот код](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7d557cb17081ece5452e6aed98e37835) воспроизодит Вашу проблему?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan , нет. Я работаю с ViewModel. Смотрите P.S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поскольку логика выбора языка более высокоуровневая, я бы вынес решение о том, какой язык использовать, на уровень `MainVM`. Как-то так:

```
class SpeechSynth
{
    public static SpeechSynth CreateByLanguage(string language) =>
        new SpeechSynth(language);

    public static SpeechSynth CreateDefault() =>
        new SpeechSynth();

    private SpeechSynth(string language)
    {
        SelectedVoice = _Synthesizer
                            .GetInstalledVoices()
                            .First(v => v.VoiceInfo.Description.Contains(language));
    }

    private SpeechSynth()
    {
        SelectedVoice = _Synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices().First();
    }
}
```

Ну и логика в VM:

```
private SpeechSynth _Speech;

//ctor
public MainViewModel()
{
    bool noFrenchInstalled = false;
    try
    {
        _Speech = SpeechSynth.CreateByLanguage("France");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        noFrenchInstalled = true;
        _Speech = SpeechSynth.CreateDefault();
    }
    // остальная инициализация
    if (noFrenchInstalled)
        MessageBox.Show("А нет французского, тю!");
}
```

В принципе, если вы не хотите показывать message box из VM, тогда превратите флаг `noFrenchInstalled` в свойство, и показывайте сообщение в UI, если оно установлено.

Comment: Спасибо, только я немного изменил - сделал выбор языка через `enum`

Comment: @Bulson: Пожалуйста! Да, enum лучше, чем строки.